# Write filesystem-dependent code in c++

Tags: c++, filesystems, preprocessor-directive

How can I write filesystem-dependent code in C++? I am writing a user level library that should handle files in different ways depending on certain features in the underlying filesystem, how can I figure that out?

For example, are there any defined preprocessor directives that expose the filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, you can use the [GetVolumeInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.  On Linux and OSX (and BSD!), you can use the [statfs](http://linux.die.net/man/2/statfs) function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any information that the preprocessor would give you on this.

Something to keep in mind is that you might be in a situation where the OS supports multiple types of filesystems. It's not inconceivable that an application might be accessing multiple filesystems at the same time on the same box.